# j2me jar api creating jar file run time

Tags: java-me, jar

java.util.jar is not avail in j2me, what if using j2me app wants to create jar file from midlet at run time ?

Answer (score 0):

at once,I put jar file of my j2me application in it's resource and then rebuild it.You can use getClass().getResourceAsStream() to access it,as other resources.